# Image Links not working on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm trying to get some very basic Social links on my website. I'm using Twitters bootstrap as well as some custom CSS.

The mobile images (with links) work great on Desktops but when testing it on a Table or Mobile device, I can not click it.

Here's the code in question: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avZOor

```css
.body {
  background-color: #105b74;
}
.header {
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  float: right;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.header ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="http://fb.com/redacted">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/BJbloCr.png" alt="Facebook Link" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/redacted">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/mOlTDAi.png" alt="Twitter Link" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/redacted">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/MxqUrM2.png" alt="Google+" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://redacted.com/contact">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/WQyMo7e.png" alt="Contact Page Link" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure. i tested your code pen example on my android device and it seams to work just fine

Comment: Works fine in Android Lollipop.

Comment: It works fine on Android!!!

Comment: Seems duplicate: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282367/clickable-website-image-not-working-on-iphone-and-android-devices>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I removed the float directive from the css file and it worked

Comment: It is not an obligation, but adding a jsFiddle (or something like) is always appreciate to quickly see the result of your change. More over, making it clear what you changed is also good!